# How to left align content in a right aligned div?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When I do this it right aligns as expected:

```
<div class="text-right">
    ...
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

I was hoping that this would cause the content to be left aligned in relation to itself, but to be right aligned within the containing div:

```
<div class="text-right">
    <div class="text-left">
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

No such luck though, it just left aligns everything.

Comment: It's not clear what you want here. In your second snippet all text content _would_ be left aligned. What's your goal?

Comment: @isherwood You're right... turns out the problem lied elsewhere. I didn't realize there were some elements with `w-100` on them. After I removed that it worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the grid system, not text alignment.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">Some text.</div>
      <div class="col-8 text-right">Some right-column text.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you truly want text alignment, your text should probably be in paragraphs that can be individually aligned.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p>Some left-aligned (by default) text.</p>
      <p class="text-right">Some right-aligned text.</p>
      <p>Some left-aligned (by default) text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I think I wasn't completely clear though. It's not just one block of text. It's some text and some other elements, and the idea is that the widest element will be right aligned and then all its siblings will be left aligned with that element. Fortunately, the solution I tried actually does work... problem was that I didn't realize there were some elements with `w-100` causing it to take up the entire column thus guaranteeing everything would always be left aligned with the column itself.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I tried actually does work. The problem was I had some elements with `w-100` causing it to take up the entire width of the column and thus ensuring everything would be left aligned with the column rather than the widest element being right aligned and everything else being left aligned to that.